# Imagemagick add whitespace

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, imagemagick

I'm using Imagemagick to join some PNG files and output them to a PDF file.

I'm using this command: `montage *.png -mode Concatenate -tile 4x2  outputA3.pdf`

But lets say that I only have 3 images available (same dimmension) and I still want to join them in a 4x2 tile.

Something like this:
(WS stands for white space)

```
| IMG1 | IMG2 | IMG3 |  WS  |
|  WS  |  WS  |  WS  |  WS  |
```

Is it possible to add white space with the dimension of the images?

If so how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you know what the width and heights of the images are why not use the `-size` option? So if you knew the images were each 20x20px then you would pass `-size 80x40`. Edit: Hmm actually that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @EvanPurkhiser , actually I do know the size of my images: `Width:413px ; Height:582px` but yes, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Concatenate` mode you can remove the gaps using the option

`-geometry '1x1+0+0<'`

The geometry flag specifies the perferred  tile and border size. The geometry of `1x1+0+0<` tells it to remove the border (the `0+0` part) and to enlarge images smaller than 1x1 (the `1x1<` part).

The `1x1` resize is necessary since if you use a 'zero geometry' it will automatically put it into concatenate mode ([see here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#concatenate)).

Comment: That worked flawlessly! I want some border so I used `-geometry '1x1+1+1<'` instead. Thank you very much!